# How to redirect routes from cloudfront to an API Gateway that contains multiple services created by serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-edge

I created an API Gateway using AWS CDK and I am using the serverless framework to create 3 different API's using the same API Gateway. My API Gateway structure looks like this:

```
/
  /service1
     /service1/{proxy}
  /service2
     /service2/{proxy}
  /service3
     /service3/{proxy}
```

I configured API Gateway as the origin of a cloudfront, redirecting requests coming from "**domain/api**" to API Gateway. The problem is that the path in API Gateway needs to match the selected path in cloudfront, so I would have to change it to something like:

```
/
  /api/service1
     /api/service1/{proxy}
  /api/service2
     /api/service2/{proxy}
  /api/service3
     /api/service3/{proxy}
```

This solution would be ok, but I can't share the "**/api**" path between multiple different services using the serverless framework. I would like the API Gateway rootPath to be "/api" and not "/", but I haven't been able to perform this configuration with the CDK. I wish I had something like this, is it possible?

```
/api
  /service1
     /service1/{proxy}
  /service2
     /service2/{proxy}
  /service3
     /service3/{proxy}
```

So that requests with /api were redirected by cloudfront to API Gateway, but could be defined as /service1 in the service, not /api/service1.

Comment: Is service1 after the root / represents a resource or a stage?, if it is a just a resource, then you can simply deploy it to a stage called api, or you can put them under a resource called api (in this case you will have to add the stage to the cloud front mapping path). For me, I use apigateway on Edge, so I'll have a managed cloudfront, that I use it with a subdomain e.g. api.mydomain.com.

Comment: It's a service. Creating a stage called api seems like a good option. I can't use a subdomain for the API as I'm using the same cloudfront for front and API's, but now I'm considering separating...